# iLO and server through same external IP

Tags: vpn, ilo

I have a HP ProLiant server which supports iLO. Also I have some services running on that server. Now, I only have one external IP address available, initially I wanted to use that IP address for a VPN to my server, but I cannot create to a server that is for example turned off. Does anybody have a proper solution for me of how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you accept" get a provider that supports multiple IP addresses" or "put the server behind a small low cost router that does all the VPN stuff" (you can get a nice mikrotik for around 60 USD max that is suitable). Otherwise this question is better served on Superuser.com as you hardly follow business practices.

Comment: You could use IPv6 for management functions, then shortage of IP addresses will be loss of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TomTom said in the comments... You want to use a router or acquire multiple IP addresses from your provider.

Placing your ILO on the public internet without any protection is also a bad idea.

Comment: That's just the problem, I only have one IP address available... A router seems the best idea, indeed. As my current setup is just for testing, I wouldn't have any security issues with iLO being publicly available. I marked this answer as correct, but of course all the credit goes to @TomTom.